# 2 jquery colorbox at one time.. can this be done?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

In my main page, I have to call a colorbox upon clicking a button. Within that colorbox there is also a button that must trigger another colorbox. Knowing the fact that a colorbox within a colorbox is not tidy enough to see, I am looking for a solution to call another colorbox even if one is being rendered. Is this possible? if yes, how can It be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using the iframe option on the first call. Doing so gives you a whole new Window environment to work with. From there, just call colorbox as normal.

This may be right for you because the iframe option allows the called content to be plain old HTML, which of course may contain a colorbox call.

Obviously, the resulting UI might not work for you but you haven't provided much about that in your questions.

Think it over.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, javascript/jquery is not my strong point, but I'll try to help with this. Please let me know if I make syntax errors by commenting and I'll edit.

Yes, this is doable. The button within the colorbox just needs to call a function from the parent page. I tend to use colorbox in iframe mode, which requires something like this:

```
parent.yourFunction()
```

If you're not using colorbox as an iframe then I think you can just call yourFunction() directly.

Then yourFunction() would need to close the colorbox using $.colorbox.close() and open a new one using $.colorbox(params...)

That should effectively replace the current colorbox with the new one.

example:

```
function replaceColorbox(){
  $.colorbox.close();
  $.colorbox(html:"<h1>Success</h1><p>This should replace the existing colorbox</p>");
  return;
}
```